# Pandas json_normalize converts column of int values to float whan one of values is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I have noticed a behaviour that I don't quite understand.

I am doing a conversion of a list of dataclass items into a dataframe.
When all values are not-None, everything works as expected:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import asdict
from pandas import json_normalize

@dataclass
class TestItem:
    name: str = None
    id: int = None


test_item_list = [
    TestItem(name='teapot', id=11),
    TestItem(name='kettle', id=12),
    TestItem(name='boiler', id=13)
]

df = json_normalize(asdict(item) for item in test_item_list)
print(df)
```

result would be this. This is working as intended:

```
     name  id
0  teapot  11
1  kettle  12
2  boiler  13
```

but if we change `test_item_list` like this:

```
test_item_list = [
    TestItem(name='teapot', id=11),
    TestItem(name='kettle', id=12),
    TestItem(name='boiler')
]
```

the output will have 'id' column as float values instead of int:

```
     name    id
0  teapot  11.0
1  kettle  12.0
2  boiler   NaN
```

`df.dtypes` will also show that id is now float64 column:

```
name     object
id      float64
dtype: object
```

How to solve this issue? In the real working example I have several more complicated item classes, can't manually explicitly convert each of them into desired column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `id` column as [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html).

```py
>>> df['id'] = df['id'].astype('Int64') # note the capital "I"

>>> print(df.dtypes)
name    object
id       Int64
dtype: object
```

Output:

```py
     name    id
0  teapot    11
1  kettle    12
2  boiler  <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, however as I mentioned above, I don't think it is a good idea to explicitly convert each column, since I have many item classes, and this would add some overcomplications.

However, I will try to make a casting, like you suggested, but dynamically according to the dataclass field type.

Comment: Actually, after thinking a bit, I realized that I don't have any float values in my data and most likely will not have to work with floats in current project, so I've decided to convert simply to convert all `float` columns that might after json_normalize into `Int64` as you suggested.